# How can I reverse the changes I made via ' repo download'

Tags: android, git

From http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html, there is a 'download' command, which let me download the change from review system.

e.g. repo download TARGET CHANGE

My question is how can I reverse the changes I made to my repo done by the 'repo download' command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed any changes you can just run:

```
repo sync
```

From "Using Repo" it says:

http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#download

```
"A repo sync should effectively remove any commits retrieved via repo download."
```